# Lagging draggable video carousel with Slick.js

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm creating a page with a draggable video carousel with Slick.js. Somehow the drag is very laggy and I couldn't find a solution. Below is my code. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.video').slick({
        centerMode: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,

});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Is this occurring while videos are playing? Are any of your videos autoplaying?

Comment: It's occurring on both, when the videos are playing and not playing

Comment: Can you include the markup for your `.video` component?